# Dotted top and bottom border shorter than text

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I want to achieve border top and bottom like below image how can I achieve with CSS tricks?

[image]

Challenge is I don't want entire width with border and it should be responsive too.

Mobile version image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCeeo.jpg and it should work in desktop and mobile browser too.

I tried with %width border but it's not working.

I wrote below code but it's not 100% perfect answer for me.

HTML:

```
<h1>How it Works</h1
```

CSS:

```
h1:before, h1:after {
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wjhnX/488/

Comment: You can try using `transform: translateX(50%); width: 50%` on the `:before,:after` as well as `text-align: center;` on the h1.

Comment: @area28 I tried that one but with responsive bigger and smaller with it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a few changes in your CSS:

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
}

h1:before, h1:after{
    position: relative;
    content: "";
    width: 30%;
    left: 35%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 5px dotted yellow;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wjhnX/492/)

**EDIT:**

If you want a fixed `width` you can add:

```
h1:before, h1:after{
    width: 150px;     /* You can change this value */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wjhnX/494/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. but I don't want to entire width border top and bottom. Want just like image. center border and only few px.

Comment: I have updated my answer. See a [new demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wjhnX/492/) ;) Also you can modify `width` and `left` to the values that solve your problem, keeping this formula: `width + 2*left = 100`.

Comment: Still there is problem. It should be work with responsive too. 
Actual mobile version image is http://i.imgur.com/XZTW28N.jpg

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. I think the image is the correct behavior, no? Can you explain a bit more what you want?

Comment: I want like fixed with of "px" line. but center of above and below text.
In your demo with bigger with line go bigger. http://awesomescreenshot.com/03559a912e

Comment: Awesome. It's perfect. What I was looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90278/discussion-between-ajmerainfo-and-lmgonzalves).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `box-shadows` also to achieve this, first create an `after` psuedo-element on top and a `before` pseudo-element on bottom then give the two of the `box-shadows`

```css
body{
 background:#09858F;
}

div{
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:100px;
}
h1{
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Calibri;
 font-size:50px;
 color:#fff;
 margin:50px;
}

h1:after{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 left:30%;
 height:10px;
 width:10px;
 background:yellow;
 top:20%;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:20px 0 0 0  yellow,40px 0 0 0  yellow,60px 0 0 0  yellow,80px 0 0 0  yellow,100px 0 0 0  yellow,120px 0 0 0  yellow,140px 0 0 0  yellow,160px 0 0 0  yellow;
}
h1:before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 left:30%;
 height:10px;
 width:10px;
 background:yellow;
 bottom:20%;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:20px 0 0 0  yellow,40px 0 0 0  yellow,60px 0 0 0  yellow,80px 0 0 0  yellow,100px 0 0 0  yellow,120px 0 0 0  yellow,140px 0 0 0  yellow,160px 0 0 0  yellow;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>How it Works</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using `radial-gradient` background image to produce the dots at the top and bottom. The output is responsive and the no. of dots at the top and bottom are determined by the width (for example, `width: 108px` produces 9 dots as `background-size` in x-axis is `12px`).

The advantage of this approach over the others is that this allows greater control over the size of the dots and the space in between the dots. The downside is the [browser support for `radial-gradient`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) which is lower (IE10+) compared to dotted border method.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.625em;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: 100;
}
h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 108px;  /* multiples of background-size in X-axis */
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgb(250, 189, 38) 30%, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgb(250, 189, 38) 30%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 12px 6px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 50% 0.125em, 50% 2em;
}
/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: rgb(9, 133, 143);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- library included to support older browsers -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<h1>How it works</h1>

<h1>How it works with long text</h1>
```

**Screenshot with large dots:**

[image]

---

All that is needed to be done to make the dots smaller in size is to reduce the color-stop percentages of the radial gradient. The smaller the percentages, the smaller the dots.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.625em;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: 100;
}
h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 108px;  /* multiples of background-size in X-axis */
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgb(250, 189, 38) 25%, transparent 35%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgb(250, 189, 38) 25%, transparent 35%);
  background-size: 12px 6px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 50% 0.125em, 50% 2em;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: rgb(9, 133, 143);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- library included to support older browsers -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<h1>How it works</h1>

<h1>How it works with long text</h1>
```

**Screenshot with smaller dots:**

[image]