# HTML text border-bottom underline

Tags: html, css, sass

I have text that needs to be underlined

```
<div><span class="text">Underlined</span><br>blah blah</div>
```

So it should look like this

```
Underlined 
   ---
blah blah
```

I am using SASS/SCSS and I have tried to use :before element however it is not showing up.

```
 &>div {
     // code 
       &:before {
         //other code
       }
     }
     .text {
         font-weight: bold; 
         &:before {
           border-bottom:red solid 1px;
         }
     }
 }
```

I have tried literally everything. I have tried span:before `span::before` `.text:before` `.text::before` etc but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Only .text {  border-bottom: 1px black dashed; } not works?

Comment: As Paulo Menezes mentioned check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mxjxgs4j/

Comment: Already answered here [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706932/dotted-top-and-bottom-border-shorter-than-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

Note that pseudo elements like `:after` and `:before` need the `content` property set.

```css
span {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

span:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:22px;
    margin-left:-11px;
    border-bottom:red dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="text">Underlined</span>
    <br>
    blah blah
</div>
```

Comment: If a question has already been answered here on SO, the appropriate action is to flag it as a duplicate, not answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```css
div{
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
}
span{
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="text">Underlined</span>blah blah</div>
```